# Programa não executa o comando While apos a leitura no scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Estava tentando fazer um programa para calcular o mmc , de dois valores inteiros,porem não consigo nem ao menos testar o meu código , já que nenhum compilador testado rodou , alguem sabe oque pode ser?[image: a tela fica assim ,sem executar os comandos]Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
int x,y,aux,primo,mmc,cont=0,i;
scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
primo=2;
mmc=1;
while(x!=1 || y!=1)
{
    if(x%primo==0)
    {
        x=x/primo;
        cont++;
    }
    if(y%primo==0)
    {
        y=y/primo;
        cont++;
    }
    if(cont==0)
    {
        aux=0;
        while(aux=0)
        {
            cont=0;
            primo++;
            for(i=2;i<primo;i++)
            {
                if(primo%i==0)
                {
                    cont++;
                }
                if(cont=0)
                {
                    aux=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    primo++;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    else
     mmc=mmc*primo;
}
printf("MMC=%d",mmc);
return 0;
}``
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você está fazendo aqui:
    aux=0;
    while(aux=0)
note que no while você está atribuindo 0 à variável aux, talvez você queira fazer:
    while(aux==0)
idem aqui:
    if(cont=0)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente vamos ao problema do seu algoritmo:

```
    if(x%primo==0)
    {
        x=x/primo;
        cont++;
    }
    if(y%primo==0)
    {
        y=y/primo;
        cont++;
    }
```

Podemos observar nessa parte que se for digitado um numero par no `scanf();`ele entrará em algum desses primeiro `if()` e consequentemente o `cout` será incrementado e nunca entrará no

```
if(cont==0)
```

logo a expressão `(x!=1 || y!=1)` nuca será satisfeita, criando então um **loop.**

O ponto é que tentar calcular o MMC usando o método de fatoração de números inteiros é um problema NP, não existindo um algoritmo que possa fazer isso de maneira eficiente.

A forma mais simples de fazer um algoritmo para calcular o MMC de dois números inteiros é utilizando a propriedade que o MMC e o MDC (máximo divisor comum) possuem;

```
                                 MMC(a,b)= a x b / (MDC(a,b))
```

Ou seja, podemos calcular o MMC utilizando o MDC. A vantagem disso é que o MDC pode ser calculado eficientemente através do algoritmo de Euclides:

```
int mdc(int a, int b){
    while(b != 0){
        int r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Após isso é só jogar o resultado na formula e está pronto o sorvetinho !

Espero ter ajudado XD